# Who is the Lord of Storm's End?

Tags: game-of-thrones

There are any references of who is the actual lord of Storm's End (Season 6 Episode 4, and the end of the last book)? since Tommen is the king an the only heir of the main Baratheon's house.

Comment: It was Stannis.... not sure what happened when the War of Five Kings started... Probably Littlefinger.... he is getting ***all*** the titles

Comment: *When* is *actual*???

Comment: I assume this is after Season 5 of the show?

Comment: Good question. I get the feeling that we need to wait to find out.

Comment: @Mooz This isn't a duplicate. The other question deals with the Iron Throne as opposed to the ancestral seat of House Baratheon.

Comment: @kuhl It's a funny situation only because a Baratheon happens to sit the Iron Throne, therefore *their* ancestral seat, Storm's End, goes to the NiL (which in this case is a bit contentious, but gets explained in the linked question).

Comment: @Mooz as long as the answer to the question is Tommen, I agree. We would need the OPs input on this one though. If the OP is asking based on the assumption that Tommen isn't legitimate (and why else would you even need to ask the question at this point) then inheritance changes. Robert Baratheons claim to the IT is that he's a cousin of the Targaryens and so technically Dany can claim the IT through him. Since its on his grandmother's side, Dany isn't a claimant to Storms End because she doesn't have a Baratheon ancestor that we know of.

Comment: @kuhl The OP was the one who marked as duplicate (hence the Community). Also, Dany's relationship means almost nothing since Robert didn't necessarily assert that claim, rather he took the Throne by force (conquest); she will most likely do the same.

Comment: @Mooz wasn't aware of that. Saw your name and that was it. If it answers the OPs question then it's a duplicate.

Comment: @kuhl [Here's how that works](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250930/252593)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beware, spoilers...

**In the books (as of A Dance of Dragons):**

> Stannis Baratheon is still alive. He would be succeeded by Shireen Baratheon.

**In the show (as of Season 6 Episode 4)**:
Tommen would have the strongest claim to Storm's End by two different means.

1) As the 'heir' of Robert Baratheon. This would be problematic (If widely known and proven)  since he is a bastard born of incest rather than Robert's true born son.

2) As the king.

> The entire, legitimate house Baratheon has been wiped out and bastards (such as Gendry) cannot inherit.

In this case the lands and holdings would pass to the crown to be kept or handed out at will.

Comment: Tommen's claim is only problematic if the truth of his ancestry were actual common and accepted knowledge. All those who make that claim lie defeated so that claim is equally powerless.

Comment: @SystemDown agreed. I assume that the issue with his claim is why the OP asked the question. I'll add something to note that it'd only be a problem if proven.

Comment: Does killing the current Lord (say *Renly*) make you legitimate Lord (say *Stannis*) yourself? As in, other then *Power resides where men believe it resides. No more and no less.* (to quote Varys).

Comment: @Ghanima no, but since Renly didn't have children, his brother would be his heir.

Comment: Your last point seems spurious to me. Where does it state that if a house fails to produce an heir then the lands `pass to the crown to be kept or handed out at will`? In fact, this is one of the reasons for Harry the Heir (he's a far-removed relative of House Arryn, but stands to inherit it in the event of Robyn Arryn's death).

Comment: @Mooz At least based on the back of the book guide to families and awoiaf, the Baratheons don't have cousins on the father's side that we're aware of. Harry the Heir is still a cousin to the Arryns. I'll dig up the specific situation I'm thinking of, but at one point a holding is seized by the crown due to the death of the family.

Comment: @mooz I'm not sure where that quote came from, but that was the law of Plantagenet England, where George R draws quite a bit of inspiration, so I'd bet it holds up

Comment: Note that not being Robert's son should also invalidate his claim to the Iron Throne, and thus he should have no claim at all for Storm's End. Interestingly, this means no one in Westeros can really claim the Iron Throne...